# Compare csv file with MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, csv, data-comparison

I am creating a program in Java and I need to compare if data in a csv file is exactly the same that exists on a mysql table?
How can i do that?
For example, i have a table "Suplyers" with columns "Id, Name and Adress".
Thanks

Below is the code that i have that read csv file and that connect to database and shows the data in the table.

> 

```
    public static void le_csv() {
            String row;
            BufferedReader csvReader = null;
            try {
                csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\ficheiros\\fornecedores.csv"));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                while ((row = csvReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] data = row.split(",");
                    System.out.println(data[0] + "\t" + data[1] + "\t" + data[2]);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                csvReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    > 
    > 
    > 
    public static void query(){
        try {
                String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/database";
                String user = "user";
                String password = "password";
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    
                String sql = "SELECT * FROM SUPLYERS";
                Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
    
                while (rs.next()) {
                    System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + "\t" + rs.getString(2) + "\t" + rs.getString(3);
                }
    
                rs.close();
                st.close();
                conn.close();
    
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

Comment: You need to show some effort from your side, what you really tried and what did not work for you.  Your current question is too broad and needs to be more focused.

Comment: I updated to the code that i have in the moment. I can read the csv and connect to the database and shows the data inside the table. I want to compare if each line has the same data but i do not know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You may collect the CSV data and DB data into lists of String and then compare the lists using `equals`:

```
    public static List<String> readCsvData() {
        List<String> csvData = new ArrayList<>();
        // use try-with-resources to auto close reader
        try (BufferedReader csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\ficheiros\\fornecedores.csv"))){
            String row;
            while ((row = csvReader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] data = row.split(",");
                row = String.join("\t", data[0], data[1], data[2]);
                System.out.println(row);
                csvData.add(row);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return csvData;
    }

    public static void initDb() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    
    public static List<String> readDbData(){
        initDb();
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/database";
        String user = "user";
        String password = "password";
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM SUPLYERS";
        List<String> dbData = new ArrayList<>();

        // use try-with-resources to auto close SQL connection, etc.
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
             Statement st = conn.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        ) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                String row = String.join("\t", rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3));
                System.out.println(row);
                dbData.add(row);
            }
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(exc);
        }
        return dbData;
    }
    
    public static boolean areCsvDataSameAsDb() {
        List<String> csvData = readCsvData();
        List<String> dbData = readDbData();
        
        return csvData.equals(dbData);
    }
```

Or you can read the data row by row to shortcut the check as soon as any discrepancy is detected.