# Comparing csv data with oracle database table using java

Tags: java, database, oracle, csv, compare

I need to compare my csv file data with the oracle database table. The data contains nearly 9000 rows. Any links and sources how can I do this.
I am using this thread, but it uses the equals method in list string, but this does not compare the data row by row both csv and database table

[Compare csv file with MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63130294/compare-csv-file-with-mysql-database)

Answer (score 1):

Java? I don't speak Java. But, as it is an Oracle database, I'd suggest another approach - an **external table**. Here's an example based on Scott's sample schema and its `DEPT` table. The CSV file contains data that "fit" that table, but - I'd like to see the differences.

`test_dept.csv` file:

```
10,ACCOUNTING,NEW YORK
20,SALES,CHICAGO
30,RESEARCH,DALLAS
40,OPERATIONS,BOSTON
50,CIA,LANGLEY
```

External table: in order to use it, there must be a directory (line #8) (Oracle object that points to a filesystem directory, usually located on the database server. It contains the csv file (line #18)); user which will be using it has to have at least `read` privilege on it:

```
SQL> create table dept_ext
  2    (deptno   char(2),
  3     dname    char(20),
  4     loc      char(20)
  5    )
  6  organization external (
  7    type oracle_loader
  8    default directory ext_dir
  9    access parameters (
 10      records delimited by newline
 11      fields terminated by ','
 12      missing field values are null
 13      ( deptno  char(2),
 14        dname   char(20),
 15        loc     char(20)
 16      )
 17    )
 18    location ('test_dept.csv')
 19  )
 20  reject limit unlimited;

Table created.
```

Does it *see* any data?

```
SQL> select * from dept_ext;

DE DNAME                LOC
-- -------------------- --------------------
10 ACCOUNTING           NEW YORK
20 SALES                CHICAGO
30 RESEARCH             DALLAS
40 OPERATIONS           BOSTON
50 CIA                  LANGLEY
```

Yes, it does. What's in the "original" `dept` table?

```
SQL> select * from dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
```

OK, so now what? As it is a "table", you can write any `select` you want, join it to other tables ... for example: which departments from the csv file don't exist in the database table?

```
SQL> select * from dept_ext
  2  where deptno not in (select deptno from dept);

DE DNAME                LOC
-- -------------------- --------------------
50 CIA                  LANGLEY
```

If I join tables on `deptno`, are there any differences in department name?

```
SQL> select e.deptno, e.dname, e.loc, d.dname, d.loc
  2  from dept_ext e join dept d on d.deptno = e.deptno
  3                             and trim(d.dname) <> trim(e.dname);

DE DNAME                LOC                  DNAME          LOC
-- -------------------- -------------------- -------------- -------------
20 SALES                CHICAGO              RESEARCH       DALLAS
30 RESEARCH             DALLAS               SALES          CHICAGO

SQL>
```

And so forth. Looks like it *might* do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The code will be very long if you try to use Java to do this. But it is convenient to compare an CSV file and a table in the Oracle database using SPL, the open-source Java package.

Suppose we have an employee table in Oracle database:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
  (EID NUMBER(8),
  NAME VARCHAR2(255),
  SURNAME VARCHAR2(255),
  GENDER VARCHAR2(255),
  STATE VARCHAR2(255),
  BIRTHDAY DATE,
  HIREDATE DATE,
  DEPT VARCHAR2(255),
  SALARY NUMBER(8)
);

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (1,'Rebecca','Moore','F','California',TIMESTAMP'1974-11-20 00:00:00.0',TIMESTAMP'2005-03-11 00:00:00.0','R&D',7000);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (2,'Ashley','Wilson','F','New York',TIMESTAMP'1980-07-19 00:00:00.0',TIMESTAMP'2008-03-16 00:00:00.0','Finance',11000);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (3,'Rachel','Johnson','F','New Mexico',TIMESTAMP'1970-12-17 00:00:00.0',TIMESTAMP'2010-12-01 00:00:00.0','Sales',9000);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (4,'Emily','Smith','F','Texas',TIMESTAMP'1985-03-07 00:00:00.0',TIMESTAMP'2006-08-15 00:00:00.0','HR',7000);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (5,'Ashley','Smith','F','Texas',TIMESTAMP'1975-05-13 00:00:00.0',TIMESTAMP'2004-07-30 00:00:00.0','R&D',16000);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (6,'Matthew','Johnson','M','California',TIMESTAMP'1984-07-07 00:00:00.0',TIMESTAMP'2005-07-07 00:00:00.0','Sales',11000);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (7,'Alexis','Smith','F','Illinois',TIMESTAMP'1972-08-16 00:00:00.0',TIMESTAMP'2002-08-16 00:00:00.0','Sales',9000);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (8,'Megan','Wilson','F','California',TIMESTAMP'1979-04-19 00:00:00.0',TIMESTAMP'1984-04-19 00:00:00.0','Marketing',11000);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (9,'Victoria','Davis','F','Texas',TIMESTAMP'1983-12-07 00:00:00.0',TIMESTAMP'2009-12-07 00:00:00.0','HR',3000);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (10,'Ryan','Johnson','M','Pennsylvania',TIMESTAMP'1976-03-12 00:00:00.0',TIMESTAMP'2006-03-12 00:00:00.0','R&D',13000);
```

And a CSV file employee.csv:

```
EID,NAME,SURNAME,GENDER,STATE,BIRTHDAY,HIREDATE,DEPT,SALARY
1,Rebecca,Moore,F,California,1974-11-20 00:00:00,2005-03-11 00:00:00,R&D,7000
3,Rachel,Johnson,F,New Mexico,1970-12-17 00:00:00,2010-12-01 00:00:00,Sales,9000
5,Ashley,Smith,F,Texas,1975-05-13 00:00:00,2004-07-30 00:00:00,R&D,16000
7,Alexis,Smith,F,Illinois,1972-08-16 00:00:00,2002-08-16 00:00:00,Sales,9000
9,Victoria,Davis,F,Texas,1983-12-07 00:00:00,2009-12-07 00:00:00,HR,3000
```

In order to get difference between the Oracle employee table and the CSV file (below is the expected result):

```
EID,NAME,SURNAME,GENDER,STATE,BIRTHDAY,HIREDATE,DEPT,SALARY
2,Ashley,Wilson,F,New York,1980-07-19 00:00:00,2008-03-16 00:00:00,Finance,11000
4,Emily,Smith,F,Texas,1985-03-07 00:00:00,2006-08-15 00:00:00,HR,7000
6,Matthew,Johnson,M,California,1984-07-07 00:00:00,2005-07-07 00:00:00,Sales,11000
8,Megan,Wilson,F,California,1979-04-19 00:00:00,1984-04-19 00:00:00,Marketing,11000
10,Ryan,Johnson,M,Pennsylvania,1976-03-12 00:00:00,2006-03-12 00:00:00,R&D,13000
```

And to calculate the intersection of Oracle employee table an the CSV file:

```
EID,NAME,SURNAME,GENDER,STATE,BIRTHDAY,HIREDATE,DEPT,SALARY
1,Rebecca,Moore,F,California,1974-11-20 00:00:00,2005-03-11 00:00:00,R&D,7000
3,Rachel,Johnson,F,New Mexico,1970-12-17 00:00:00,2010-12-01 00:00:00,Sales,9000
5,Ashley,Smith,F,Texas,1975-05-13 00:00:00,2004-07-30 00:00:00,R&D,16000
7,Alexis,Smith,F,Illinois,1972-08-16 00:00:00,2002-08-16 00:00:00,Sales,9000
9,Victoria,Davis,F,Texas,1983-12-07 00:00:00,2009-12-07 00:00:00,HR,3000
```

We just need a number of lines of SPL code:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | =ORACLE.query@x("SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE") |
| 2 | =file("employee.csv").import@ct(EID:decimal,NAME,SURNAME,GENDER,STATE,BIRTHDAY,HIREDATE,DEPT,SALARY:decimal) |
| 3 | =INTERSECT=[A1,A2].merge@oi(EID,NAME,SURNAME,GENDER,STATE,BIRTHDAY,HIREDATE,DEPT,SALARY) |
| 4 | =MINUS=[A1,A2].merge@od(EID,NAME,SURNAME,GENDER,STATE,BIRTHDAY,HIREDATE,DEPT,SALARY) |

SPL offers JDBC driver to be invoked by Java. Just store the above SPL script as cmp.splx and invoke it in Java as you call a stored procedure:

```
…
Class.forName("com.esproc.jdbc.InternalDriver");
con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:esproc:local://");
st=con.prepareCall("call cmp()");
st.execute();
…
```